# Adding a language that Calibre does not recognize

Tags: calibre, language, customization

I want to add languages that Calibre does not have in its database, such as Farsi (an alias for "Persian") and Hindavi (the precursor to Urdu and Hindi), so that I can use those languages in the Languages field for books. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Farsi**

Speakers of Persian (and related languages) usually use Farsi in their native languages to refer to Persian in the same way a French speaker would use *Français* to refer to French. However, no French speaker would ask a software developer to use *Français* also in English GUIs.

If you want to have *Farsi* as a menu option, you'll need to change the UI language to Persian or a related language.

**Hindavi**

Since Calibre uses ISO language codes internally and there are no ISO codes for *Hindavi/Hindustani*, it's not possible to add a *Hindavi* menu option. You'll have to use Hindi.